# execute @e with scoreboard does not work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a squid with a custom name of "Create_Pig_Alter", and whenever it is "standing" on stone, I want to set a scoreboard objective for the squid.  I've tried the following command, but it isn't working:

```
/execute @e[name=Create_Pig_Alter] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ stone /scoreboard players set @e PigAlterProgress 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that command running on a clock?

Answer (score 1):

"detect" syntax for `/execute`:

```
/execute <target> X Y Z detect X Y Z <block> <Damage> <command>
```

You are missing the Damage value of the block. You can set the value to -1 to signify any value. Fixed command using a value of 0 for regular smooth stone:

```
/execute @e[name=Create_Pig_Alter] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ stone 0 /scoreboard players set @e PigAlterProgress 1
```

Answer (score -1):

scoreboard can't have more than 15 chars so "PigAlterProgress" is too long.
And indeed you must use a fill/setblock clock in those cases.

Comment: The character limit is 16, which "PigAlterProgress" falls within range of.